# How to use string to call function in a class?

Tags: c++

I hope to use map library to call a function by a string with the function name, I've tested the following example and everything are working well.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef void (*pFunc)();
map<string, pFunc> strFuncMap;

void func1()
{
    printf("this is func1!\n");
}

void buildMap()
{
    strFuncMap["func1"] = &func1;// 
}

void callFunc(const std::string& str)
{
    (*strFuncMap[str])();
}

int main()
{
    buildMap();

    callFunc("func1");
    return 0;
}
```

However, as I define all these things in a class, there is a compiler error occur:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class theClass {
public:
    typedef void (*pFunc)();
    map<string, pFunc> strFuncMap;

    void func1()
    {
        printf("this is func1!\n");
    }

    void buildMap()
    {
        strFuncMap["func1"] = &func1;// a value of type cannot be assigned to an entity of type
    }

    void callFunc(const std::string& str)
    {
        (*strFuncMap[str])();
    }
};


int main()
{
    theClass a;
    a.buildMap();

    a.callFunc("func1");
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to solve this problem for a couple of hours. Or is there any other way to use string to call function in a class? I will very appreciate if someone can help me. THANKS!!

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the mistake I did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `func1` is a member function and the syntax for member functions is different.

You need a map of member function pointers (offsets)

```
typedef void (theClass::*pFunc)();
map<string, pFunc> strFuncMap;
```

Then you can store the pointer with

```
strFuncMap["func1"] = &theClass::func1;
```

And you need an object to call a member function

```
(this->*strFuncMap[str])();
```

The final code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class theClass {
public:
    typedef void (theClass::*pFunc)();
    map<string, pFunc> strFuncMap;

    void func1()
    {
        printf("this is func1!\n");
    }

    void buildMap()
    {
        strFuncMap["func1"] = &theClass::func1;
    }

    void callFunc(const std::string& str)
    {
        (this->*strFuncMap[str])();
    }
};


int main()
{
    theClass a;
    a.buildMap();

    a.callFunc("func1");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use your final code!

Comment: And if various objects and classes are involved, one would need do type erasure hacks in way similar to what some frameworks do for signal-slot architecture.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void (*pFunc)();
```

This declares `pFunc` to be the type of *function pointers*. That is, the type of pointers to functions which exist at the top-level. This excludes member functions, lambda functions, and functors. Consider

```
using pFunc = std::function<void()>
```

Now your type will correctly accept anything that can reasonably be interpreted as a callable object. Note that member functions still need to be wrapped in a lambda, since you're closing around `this`.

```
strFuncMap["func1"] = [this]() { this->func1(); };
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the mistake I did